# After deleting log files, Ubuntu server still saying there is no space

Tags: ubuntu

My Ubuntu server has stopped due to a lack of disk space. I deleted some log files which has grown huge very quickly. But `df -h` still shows I have no space left. When I run `du -sh /*` I can see that I should have plenty of disk space left after deleting the logs.

I ran `lsof +L1`  and it brought up two files: `/var/log/mail.log` and `/var/log/mail.err`. These are two logs I had deleted. I restarted apache, postfix and mysql (mysql wont restart because of lack of disk space, it think) but still `df -h` shows no space.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case the files are probably managed by syslog.  You may have rsyslog, sysklogd or syslog-ng.  From memory I think rsyslog is the default, so try:

sudo service rsyslog restart

This should release the files, and allow them to actually get cleaned up.  Until the last filehandle closes, the filesystem can't free up space.

(or you could do like a Windows admin and just reboot of course...)

Comment: glad to hear :)

Comment: Ouch, low blow.  Bad Windows admins reboot.  Good ones know how to troubleshoot and correct issues well enough to keep the system up... until the monthly flood of reboot-requiring Windows Updates, anyway. :)

Comment: @HopelessN00b - yeah, I know.  Bad Windows admins or Windows admins who learned their trade 10 years ago when that was the recommended fix.  Mind you, I would have wanted to be a Windows admin yesterday - no Linux leapsecond bug!

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart the service that created these logs, as they have a lock on these logs. eg. If it's apache, just restart apache and usage should go down.

Comment: ok, I get it now. I restarted rsyslog and its working now. Thanks for the help

Comment: You should be able to release the space by causing rsyslog to reopen its files.  `sudo killall -HUP rsyslogd` or `sudo reload rsyslog` should do it.  Try installing logrotate, which should periodically rotate your logs for you.

Comment: @BillThor just installed logrotate, works a charm, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Next time this happens you should check with `fuser` if the file is in active use by a process. If so either stop that process, then delete, or use `cp /dev/null TARGETFILE` to reduce the file-size to zero (this will not change the file-handle, and you do not have to restart anything).